# How to separate objects which have the same color with openCv

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, object-detection

For an internship I need to detect and count some pigs. I can separate them from the background but not separate one from another when they are too close. I'm starting to learn image processing and OpenCv so maybe I'm doing bad. Do you have any advice for me?

You can see the image without background here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npek3.png]

Comment: Welcome! Your post in its current form is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Share your code if possible. Tell us about your current approach.